# Is it possible to tell scaladoc to make all links to sources to open in a new tab?

Tags: scala, scaladoc

Currently, scaladoc tries to open all links in the same frame - and it results in errors if the source location is unable to work in a frame (for example, github pages).

For example: [Scallop](http://rogach.github.com/scallop/#org.rogach.scallop.Scallop%24)

Trying to open the source by left-clicking on a link results in *nothing* in Chrome and error in Opera.

Is there a way to fix that behavior?

Comment: Results in nothing in Firefox too, although, a simple workaround is to middle-click to open in a new tab

Comment: @LuigiPlinge - yes, I know that. But consider user who doesn't know that - he'll be very confused.

Comment: Re-name your souce file `middle_click_here.scala`?

Comment: @LuigiPlinge - There would be some problems with namespaces ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Scala 2.10, opening source in a separate windows is the default.

Comment: Ah. Then I just have to wait a bit :) Thanks!